# set shadow onclick on textview which are dynamically created programmatically Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am creating dynamicly textViews in my app and what i want to do is on click event to add shadow or something to make it noticable that it's clicked here is part of my code

```
    SD[iL]=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    SD[iL].setText(Html.fromHtml(Sv));
    SD[iL].setTypeface(tf);
    SD[iL].setTextSize(21.7f);
    SD[iL].setTag(iL);
    SD[iL].setPadding(dpToPx(5), dpToPx(3), dpToPx(5), 0);          

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.setMargins(dpToPx(6), 0, 0, 0);
    SD[iL].setLayoutParams(params);
    SD[iL].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...Something
            }

        }
    });
    LinearLay.addView(SD[iL]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
 SD[iL].setShadowLayer(4, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: i've tried something like that but what i want to achive is onClick event that will change the clicked textview, not to set the shaddow before it's clicked

Comment: But you can also implement this after on click event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using

```
void android.widget.TextView.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color)
```